# Python function expects a tuple, what I have is a list. How do I call this function?

Tags: python, list, tuples

The function `record()` in the [pyshp](https://code.google.com/p/pyshp/) module expects a sequence as input:

```
outfile.record('First','Second','Third')
```

What I have is a list:

```
row = ['First','Second','Third']
```

When I call the `record()` function like this:

```
outfile.record(row)
```

I get a `tuple index out of range` error. It turns out the function receives

```
(['First','Second','Third'],)
```

How do I call `record` correctly?
I have tried

```
outfile.record((row[i] for i in range(len(row)))
```

but that doesn't work either.

Comment: That is not a sequence that it's expecting; it's several arguments. "sequence" is a generic term for list, tuple, string, etc.... i.e., iterable things, but still single, specific objects. `outfile.record` expects you to pass more than one thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
outfile.record(*row)
```

This will unpack a sequence into individual arguments. This is a [formal description of this syntax from the language reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls), and this is an [informal description from the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Note there is a similar construct which will unpack a mapping (dict) into keyword arguments:

```
functiontakingkeywordarguments(**mydict)
```

Comment: Thanks! I searched the python docs for this, but could not find the reference. I would have expected it here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 7):

```
outfile.record(*row)
```

The * in this case means "unpack." It will unpack a list into a series of arguments.

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists